# Induced Current Density of Circular Disk

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, integration, electromagnetic-induction

Hello I'm having trouble setting up the correct form of the Maxwell-Faraday law to help me find the induced current density on a disk in an alternating magnetic field. The problem is set out as follows:

A thin conducting disk of thickness h, diameter D, and conductivity σ is placed in a uniform magnetic field $B = B_{0}sinωt$ parallel to the axis of the disk.

1. Find the induced current density as a function of distance from the axis of the disk.
2. What is the direction of this current?

I believe I need to use $\oint \vec E \cdot d \vec l = - \frac {d \phi} {dt}$ to find the magnitude of the electric field, after which I can use $\vec J = \sigma \vec E$ to find the current density.

I have already found:
$$\varepsilon = - \frac {d \phi} {dt} = -B_{0} \omega \cos{\omega t} \left( \frac D 2 \right)^2 \pi$$

What I could use some help with is setting up the integral on the left hand side. I would appreciate any advice on this thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This approach might be useful.  I believe the left hand side integral will be

$$
\oint \vec E \cdot d \vec l=Er\int_{0}^{2 \pi}\mathrm{d} \theta=2 \pi Er
$$

where $r$ is the radial distance from the center of the disk.

Please note that the rate of change of flux, $\frac {d \phi} {dt}$, should also be a function of $r$ and not fixed to a particular $D$.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Ah thank you very much, do you think you could explain a little about the how you worked out thats the integral you needed? I seem to have a general problem with identifying right approach to use with these kinds of problems. Also if $\phi = \vec B \cdot \vec A$ and both $\vec B$ and $\vec A$ point in the same direction why would $\frac {d \phi} {dt}$ be a function of $r$? Is it not just a case of multiplying their magnitudes?